# How to place include in other place

Tags: php

I make  some function in php, but I am getting stuck

```
if (isset($_GET['page']) ) 
{
    $open = __DIR__.'/../view/html/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
    if (file_exists($open)){
        include $open; //<<<<can i//
    }
    else {
        "echo "The file not found";
    }
}
```

1. If true, I want to include that file in another place, but how?
2. I am trying to put the code in where I want, but the `__DIR__` is not working as I expected. I don't know how to fix it to become right. Solution cannot be found in the tutorial.

Comment: using this code, you will become an another victim of `lfi` attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
if( isset( $_GET['page'] ) ) {
    switch( strtolower( $_GET['page') ) ) {
        case 'download':
            include '../download.php';
            break;
        case 'blog':
            include '../blog.php';
            break;
        // ... And so on
        default:
            echo 'File not found';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No file specified';
}
```

This way you have full control over which files can be included!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do like this.

Use `file_get_contents()`

```
if (file_exists($open)){
    file_get_contents($open);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is `yes`, that will work. Whether or not you should use `readfile()`, `file_get_contents()` or `include` depends on the contents of the file. If you have php code in that file, you need either `include` or `require`. But this actually brings up another problem.

As mentioned in the comments by @anonymous, you are exposing yourself to an LFI attack. To resolve this, pages should be defined as a whitelisted array. You should then check if the page is in the whitelisted array. If it is not, do not attempt to open that file.

```
$pages = array(
    'page1',
    'page2'
);
```

Then you can make a reference and check if it exists.

```
if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)){
    //now check for the file
    $open = __DIR__.'/../view/html/'.$_GET['page'].'.php';
    if(file_exists($open)){
        include $open;
    }
} else {
    //page does not exist, redirect them elsewhere.
    header('Location: http://example.com/404.php');
}
```